# How to create dark/light theme in Bootstrap 5 with React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, darkmode, lightmode

I'm stuck with developing a light/dark mode with bootstrap in react, how can I do this? Is there any example video or code or anything you know about it? I found in youtube only plain css and since I'm using bootstrap I'm afraid that won't work for my project, it could just change my background but I want to change also some structures of my site.

Answer (score 4):

bootstrap 5.3 introduced [color modes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/) to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I can help !
You need to use states as the theme btn is toggled, and update properties according to that, I have previously worked upon that so I am sharing link of that project: https://satellite-system.github.io/TextUtils---React-js-Web/
, github link : https://github.com/Satellite-system/TextUtils---React-js-Web

Hope it will help.
It was actually a project from youtube, but I have forgot its channel.

Comment: I think passing all the theme modes as props is not good way. Need global styling for that

Comment: I agree with @sayinmehmet47 that passing the theme (or `mode`) as a prop to individual components is likely not a healthy way to go.  Likely use of Context API or building your own hook (useTheme??) would be cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

how I would approach this

1. use LocalStorage to store user selected mode
   2.create a component which fetches this data from LS and usesContext
2. export the context and use it in component wherever required

Comment: this is better way I think

Answer (score 0):

Copy Paste this Line in your Html Head tag

```
enter code here
<link 
 ref="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-dark-5@1.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap-dark.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: is there a scss version of this for React?