# what is best way to set BLACK (#000000) background, light text in bootstrap ideally without SASS?

Tags: css, less, bootstrap-5, dark-theme

I have a nascent website. I've written the markup using Bootstrap 5, defining menus, basic layout, etc. I want a **black** background (#000000, not gray-800 or gray-900, etc.) as a default throughout the site. I've tried this, which has a sweeping effect, but there are problems:

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

The main thing I'm worried about is that all the nice bootstrap layout and features -- little drop shadows, modal dialogs, carousels, etc. -- might suddenly be badly formatted. One thing that immediately jumps out is some thin white lines around various heroes like this one:

```html
    <div class="row p-4 pb-0 pe-lg-0 pt-lg-5 align-items-center rounded-3 border shadow-lg">
        <div class="col-lg-5 p-3 p-lg-5 pt-lg-3">
            <h1 class="display-4 fw-bold lh-1">Get ready for <span class="the_tower">The Tower</span></h1>
            <p class="lead">New album <a href="/music/the-tower" class="badge bg-danger the_tower" style="cursor: pointer;">The Tower</a> drops October 6 on all major streaming platforms.
            Subscribe on YouTube so you can see our latest news!</p>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start mb-4 mb-lg-3">
                <a href="/music/the-tower" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 me-md-2 fw-bold">Show me <span class="the_tower">The Tower</span></a>
                <a href="https://youtu.be/6nbQNWRJKg0" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg px-4 me-md-2 fw-bold">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-1 p-0 overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
            <iframe style="aspect-ratio: 16/9;" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/6nbQNWRJKg0?rel=0&amp;loop=1" title="YouTube video player" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also see that all the nice, subtle gradations in shading and stuff just get lost.

I've searched around and seen [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082529/how-to-properly-introduce-a-light-dark-mode-in-bootstrap) which focus on toggling between dark and light mode. That is not my goal. I just want my website to be black/dark for all visitors, and keep all the nice things about bootstrap. Some introduce [SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667437/create-new-color-scheme-for-dark-light-mode-in-bootstrap-sass) or [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73170897/how-to-create-dark-light-theme-in-bootstrap-5-with-react) and I'd very much like to avoid both of those, although LESS might be tolerable if I absolutely must compile some CSS. I also found [this janky video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36DEbN6O1tY) with computer voiceover which seems to involve a lot of markup.

Surely there is some simple way to take one's bootstrap markup and make it dark-themed? This seems like such a fundamental request. I'm shocked it's not described in the bootstrap docs.

Comment: @adam Thanks, but that looks like 3.4 -- i'm working with 5? (EDIT: i see that 5.2 is here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/overview/ )

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up right (not too difficult with all editor extensions), you can have bootstrap compiled on change of code. Then all you need is to change this line `$body-bg: $white !default;` in file `_variables.scss` - and it will automatically compile. A great bonus is you can combine bootstrap variables with your code, and your code with bootstrap's variables.

This can be the skeleton of your project `style.scss`:
from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73114678/3807365

```scss
// my-bootstrap-and-styles.scss

// your overrides
$primary : #FEBC35;

// include bootstrap.scss
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";   

// Then add your additional custom code here
.my-primary-div {
  background: $primary;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: this post might make sense to someone more familiar with SASS, but it's totally greek to me. Furthermore, I suspect I'd have to choose a whole bunch of colors and design my own theme? Has *no one* created a simple dark theme for bootstrap that one can simply install with a stylesheet?

Comment: you can find already made themes I'm sure. like https://vinorodrigues.github.io/bootstrap-dark-5/

Comment: I have been over that vino github page quite a bit. First, the background is not **black**. Secondly, the content is almost entirely focused on dark *mode*, i.e., toggling modes. I do see that the link you've provided has some very basic information about how to just install one of his themes, and this is helpful. Thank you.